# cmd batch to listen to output of console application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, batch-file, azure

I'm starting a Console Application from a batch file as a `background`  `Startup Task` in a Cloud Project.

i have a batch file that will start the application and print messages to log file:

```
   $logfile = %LOGFOLDER%/StartupLogFile.txt
   "Starting console application" >> $logfile // print message to txt file 
  `MyConsoleApplication.exe -parameter1 value ...-parameterN valueN
```

The Conosole Application may file due to incorrect parameters and i would like to print that to the logfile. 
Is there anyway to "listen" to the application output and print it to log?

Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MyConsoleApplication.exe -parameter1 value ...-parameterN valueN 2>>%LOGFOLDER%StartupLogFile.txt
```

`>` or `1>` will redirect STDOUT

`2>`will redirect STDERR

to redirect both streams, use `command >>logfile 2>&1`

**Edit:**
you can make a complete logfile like this:

```
echo This is my logfile >logfile.txt
echo **** Starting application at %date% %time% >>logfile.txt
myconsoleapplication.exe -parameter1 value1 >>logfile.txt 2>&1
echo **** End of application at %date% %time% >>logfile.txt
```

the single `>` will write a new (or overwrite an existing) file, the `>>` will append to the file.

Comment: works like a charm, thanks! is there any way to add time&&date before log entries from MyConsoleApplication.exe? can i somehow use echo %date% %time% for this also?